# How to enable auto logon for Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10

I am running Windows 10 Pro on an Intel ComputeStick (Mod # STK1AW32SC). Ideally, I would like to automatically log into a standard user account (an Assigned Access account for running just one app) whenever it restarts or boots, such as when there is a power outage.

I have found [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions), however, I am confused about step 3. In `\Winlogon` I see two more directories `GPExtensions` and `VolatileUserMgrKey`, as well as two files?: `AlternateShells` and `AutoLogonChecked`.

I do not see the ones the documentation says: `AutoAdminLogon`, `DefaultUserName` or `DefaultPassword`.

I've never done this before so I don't want to screw anything up, thanks!

For reference I'm pretty sure this Windows version is `32 bit`.

Comment: Did you set up any password for that normal admin user account? If not then Windows usually does not ask to enter password.

Comment: Have you tried `netplwiz` ? Click Start, type netplwiz, hit Enter. Disable the top box, then supply credentials for the account you want to auto-log.

Comment: @Ramhound Perhaps, but I used `netplwiz` which is different from the command typed in the link. It would be beneficial to know both in my opinion.

Comment: The question states Windows 10 _Pro_. This is not a duplicate of the question "Does Windows 7 allow auto-login with a stored password..." The netplwiz app does not have the checkbox "Users must enter a username..."

Answer (score 2):

If anyone in the future needs an answer to this it is actually really simple.

In `Run`, open the  `netplwiz` application, choose the `User Name` that you would like auto-login to apply to, and finally, uncheck the box that states: "Users must enter a username and password to use this computer".

Click `OK` and restart computer to test.

Comment: @Ramhound Couldn't tell you, I'm not familiar with Windows XP or Windows in general.

Answer (score -1):

I found a very descriptive article on enabling auto-login on Windows 10.  This also makes use of the SysInternal's Autologin utility.

Can you try this and see if it helps for you:

https://www.top-password.com/blog/enable-disable-automatic-login-in-windows-10/

Comment: We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but please do not provide answers that are only a hyperlink.  While the information may be valuable, if the source web page ever goes offline the answer is essentially useless.  Quote all of the pertinent excerpts from the article within your answer, then you can still provide the hyperlink to cite your source.   Please see the following article from our Help Center:  [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please do not link to that particular site, it has absolutely no substance to its content, it exists for one reason search engine results